# Adding white space to the right of a string

Tags: javascript

How I can add a white space to the right of a string `str+= '+';` ?
I tried `str+= '+'+' ';` but it doesn'r seem to work.

Comment: str+= '+'; - you already adding '+' sign to the existing string with this, why not just: str+= '+  ';??? Could you post your whole code... context is missing, what you want to do, exactly?

Comment: Put your code and what you want to do please explain. This question is not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, you should try :

```
str = str + ' ';
```

More concise :

```
str += ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

strring strwithspace = str.PadRight(1);